# How to identify which Chrome extension is redirecting traffic?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, malware, redirection, debug

By chance I noticed that sometimes when I access bookdepository.com I get redirected to a strange URL before landing on that page. Apparently some rogue extension is hijacking the request to first redirect to an affiliate website. It does not always happen (likely they only do it every X minutes) but I anticipated it and managed to capture the network log which sadly didn't tell me too much. Seems that the request gets a 307 "internal redirect" to the affiliate link:

[image]

in the above image the request initiated by addthis is, I'm almost certain, a request made from the page I was previously on before navigating to bookdepository so it's not relatedMy question is, how to identify which extension is hijacking the request? Since the extension is not always doing it I can't easily disable all extensions and keep trying each one separately. Is there somehow a way to set a sort of breakpoint at the point each extension processes the navigation request?

EDIT: I have found about chrome://net-export/  which is supposed to be the way to figure out this info. The strange thing is that the 307 redirect was not listed in the log I generated.

Digging some more I see something I missed yesterday, this is the original request to bookdepistory.com (I type the addresses in the URL bar and hit enter). You can see that while the request URL is bookdepository, the host connected to is httpslinks.me

[image]

Is this a bad DNS response?

Comment: " Apparently some rogue extension is hijacking the request" How do you know this for sure?

Comment: @Moab What other alternatives do you have in mind?

Comment: compromised website

Answer (score 0):

My wild guess is that bookdepository.com or one of its resources has been temporarily moved to another server or is accidentally, incorrectly configured to indicate that such a situation is so.  (A 307 Temporary Redirect message is an HTTP response status code indicating that the requested resource has been temporarily moved to another URI, as indicated by the special Location header returned within the response.)  It could be one of their advertisers? Are you blocking ads?

A) Until you find a better way then use the idea youcame up with to disable them all and enable one by one over a certain period of time and narrow it down that way. (Only enable one at a time though, don't confuse the issue by having more than one enabled, it will speed the process).

B) Wireshark is always very helpful

C) In the meantime you could always block the connection if it is to the same address everytime (What is, if you know, the address?)

D) Are you using any firewall? (Which?)

E) If it isn't inconvenient or an intrusion into your privacy could you provide a list of the addons/extensions? (I don't mean to pry).